# EntityFramework Code First Adding unnecessary foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two classes in my Pocos

```
public class Listing
{
    public int ListingId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Seller")]
    public int SellerId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Seller { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ItemCategory { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ItemName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfPublish { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool SaleStatus { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Buyer")]
    public Nullable<int> BuyerId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Buyer { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string SecondName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Listing> Listings { get; set; }
```

When I migrate this onto the database I get BuyerId, SellerId and User_UserId

The User_UserId column is totally unnecessary but I am not sure what to do with my code in order to remove it.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766591/ef-code-first-duplicate-foreign-keys-one-from-name-convention-one-from-naviga)

Comment: I already have Data Annotation on my properties

Answer (score 1):

`Seller` and `Buyer` navigation properties in `Listing` class define *two* many to one relationships. But there is *single* collection navigation property `Listings` in `User` class. Since EF does not know to which of the two relationships it should be mapped, it simply considers it being a *third* relationship with no corresponding reference navigation property and default by convention FK name `User_UserId`.

You need to map the `Listings` property to one of the reference navigation properties. One way to do that is by using the `InverseProperty` attribute. Or replace it with *two* collection navigation properties and map them to the corresponding reference navigation properties.

Shortly, replace

```
public virtual ICollection<Listing> Listings { get; set; }
```

with

```
[InverseProperty("Seller")]
public virtual ICollection<Listing> SellerListings { get; set; }
[InverseProperty("Buyer")]
public virtual ICollection<Listing> BuyerListings { get; set; }
```